# Chart js Datalabels styling

Tags: javascript, chart.js, styling

So I'm using the datalabels plugin for Chartjs on a bar chart. Each label has data for monthly and 7 days prior. I want the datalabels to be colored red for monthly black for 7 days prior. the color feature in options groups 2 bars together and displays 2 red 2 black 2 red 2 black in chunks as appose to individually.

Heres a link to the outputted chart. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XKv0.jpg

```
import Chart from "chart.js";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";

require("../../Row4/Row4Charts/RoundedBars.js");

export default class Cancellations7daysChart extends Component {
    Cancellations7daysChart = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        const Cancellations7daysChart = this.Cancellations7daysChart.current.getContext(
            "2d"
        );

        new Chart(Cancellations7daysChart, {
            type: "bar",
            data: {
                labels: ["DSL", "FTTC", "FTTP", "GFast"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Monthly",
                        data: [7, 19, 2, 0],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "rgba(255, 9, 49)",
                            "rgba(255, 9, 49)",
                            "rgba(255, 9, 49)",
                            "rgba(255, 9, 49)"
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            "rgba(0, 193, 189)",
                            "rgba(255, 9, 49)",
                            "rgba(0, 193, 189)",
                            "rgba(0, 193, 189)"
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        pointRadius: 4,
                    },

                    {
                        label: "7 days prior",
                        data: [2, 11, 5, 3],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)",
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)",
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)",
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)"
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)",
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)",
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)",
                            "rgba(208, 210, 211)"
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        pointRadius: 6,
                    }

                ]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                cornerRadius: 6,
                cutoutPercentage: 65,
                angleLines: {
                    display: true
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                label: {
                    usePointStyle: true
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    labels: {
                        filter: function (legendItem, Cancellations7daysChart) {
                            return !legendItem.text.includes("Monthly");
                        }
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    ticks: {
                        maxTickLimit: 1,
                        max: 15,
                        display: false
                    },

                    //yaxes change
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            gridLines: {
                                drawBorder: false,
                                display: false
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                display: false
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    //xaxes change
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                //Change font here
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                drawBorder: false,
                                display: false,
                                scaleShowLabels: false
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        color: ["red", "black", "red", "black", "red", "black", "red", "black"],
                        align: "end",
                        anchor: "end"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas
                    id="Cancellations7daysChart"
                    ref={this.Cancellations7daysChart}
                    width={360}
                    height={360}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a function to change the colors depending their label:

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
        color: function(context) {
            var index = context.dataIndex;
            var value = context.dataset.data[index];
            var valueRed = context.dataset.label;

            if(valueRed === 'Monthly') {
                return value = 'red';
            } else {
                return value = '#000';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lGRvkZKPW9ZJyMLGBU1N?p=preview)

More info about formatting in the plugin's page: [Scriptable Options](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/options.html#scriptable-options)